# Filepond is there a way to send revert when large chunked file is canceled mid upload?

Tags: filepond

The revert request is only sent when the file is uploaded completely.

I want to send the revert request if the user cancels the file while it's still uploading.

[File still Uploading Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0azoB.jpg)

The Folder ID is returned from first POST request so we have the Folder ID.

I have looked through documentations and GitHub and found this [GitHub pull 757](https://github.com/pqina/filepond/pull/757) but don't know how to do it.

Everything works I just want to send the revert when the user cancels.

Here is my code

```
<input type="file" name="files" id="files" multiple>
<script>
    FilePond.create(document.getElementById("files"), {
        name: 'files',
        allowMultiple: true,
        chunkUploads: true,
        chunkSize: 1024 * 1024 * 50, // 50MB
        chunkRetryDelays: [],
        maxFileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 1024, // 1 GB
        server: {
            url: '{{ url('upload') }}',
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `FilePond:process-file.abort` event to detect when a file upload is aborted. This event is fired whenever the file is removed before it has finished uploading.

You can then call the `FilePond.revert(id)` method to revert the file upload.

Here is an example:

```
FilePond.create(document.getElementById("files"), {
    name: 'files',
    allowMultiple: true,
    chunkUploads: true,
    chunkSize: 1024 * 1024 * 50, // 50MB
    chunkRetryDelays: [],
    maxFileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 1024, // 1 GB
    server: {
        url: '{{ url('upload') }}',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
        }
    }
});

FilePond.setOptions({
    server: {
        revert: (uniqueFileId, load, error) => {
            // make request to revert the file upload here
            // once done, call load() or error()
        }
    }
});
```

Alternatively, you could also use the `FilePond:process-file.remove` event. This event is fired whenever a file is removed, whether it has finished uploading or not. You can then call the `FilePond.revert(id)` method to revert the file upload.

documentation: https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/patterns/api/server/#revert

Comment: This event is not triggered when the user cancels the file. It's only triggered when the file is selected. so I don't know how it can help?

Comment: Sorry I think I misunderstood. Updating my answer

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have checked the events and after a lot of debugging Filepond does not set `serverId` to the file while it is still uploading so revert doesn't work Filepond only sets the `serverId` after the file is completely finished uploading. If I can get the `serverId` (Folder ID returned from first POST request) I will make a custom request on `FilePond:processfileabort` event with the `serverId`